# Issues building and installing a created R package

Tags: r, package

I have created an R package (not yet on CRAN) and sent it to a colleague (as a .zip file).

Unfortunately, they were unable to properly build/install it without R throwing an error.

The error received was:

```
Error: Command failed (1)
In addition: Warning message:
The following packages are referenced using Rcpp::depends attributes however    are not listed in the Depends, Imports or LinkingTo fields of the package     DESCRIPTION file: RcppProgress
```

To create the package, I used the RcppArmadillo.package.skeleton() function in R v. 3.4.3.

I works for me, but not for my colleague.

My method in building/installing is:

```
build("package name") # creates a .tar.gz file
install("package name")
```

Would simply sending the .tar.gz file to my colleague and simply running install() work?

Here is the DESCRIPTION file:

```
Package: HACSim
Type: Package
Title: Iterative simulation of species haplotype accumulation curves
Version: 1.0
Date: 2018-04-06
Author: Jarrett Phillips
Maintainer: Jarrett Phillips 
Description: Iterative simulation of species haplotype accumulation curves for assessment of sampling completeness
License: GPL (>= 3)
NeedsCompilation: Yes
Imports: ape (>= 5.0), 
     boot (>= 1.3-20), 
     investr (>= 1.4.0), 
     mgcv (>= 1.8-23), 
     pegas (>= 0.10), 
     Rcpp (>= 0.12.16), 
     scam (>= 1.2-2)
LinkingTo: Rcpp, 
           RcppArmadillo
```

and NAMESPACE

```
useDynLib(HACSim, .registration=TRUE)
importFrom(Rcpp, evalCpp)
importFrom(ape, base.freq)
importFrom(ape, read.dna)
importFrom(boot, boot)
importFrom(boot, boot.ci)
importFrom(investr, predFit)
importFrom(MASS, mvrnorm) 
importFrom(mgcv, gam) 
importFrom(mgcv, gam.check)  
importFrom(mgcv, predict.gam)
importFrom(pegas, haplotype)
importFrom(rootSolve, uniroot.all)
importFrom(rootSolve, multiroot)
importFrom(scam, scam)
importFrom(scam, scam.check)
importFrom(scam, predict.scam)
exportPattern("^[[:alpha:]]+")
```

Comment: Can you point to your code, or a mockup replicating the issue? This "works for us" (TM).

Comment: which are the packages you used in your new package? It seems to be a dependency problem ...

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim The packages are: 'ape', 'boot', 'investr', 'mgcv', 'pegas' and 'scam', along with 'Rcpp' and 'RcppArmadillo' of course. I got it to install on my iMac by simply doing install() (and not build() first). But this may only have worked going from one Mac (MacBook Pro) to another (iMac)

Comment: Jarret, there are many problems that can arise when building a `DESCRIPTION` file for a package. Many (most?) of them are those that seasoned packagers have made two or more times, but there are too many to be able to know "for certain" based on what little you've provided. If it's on github (the easiest), provide a link. If not (many of my packages are non-GH), I suggest you post *at least* the `DESCRIPTION` and `NAMESPACE` files for the package. Otherwise, it's speculation and very likely to be closed as non-reproducible.

Comment: if those persons use another R version than you (e.g. 3.4.1 and you 3.4.3), then also their dependencies might be different versions and in addition, these dependencies might be dependent on libraries in the system which are different from yours and that all can probably break  your package ...

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim The person is using the same R version

Comment: @r2evans My package is in a private GitHub repo. I will post the DESCRIPTION and NAMESPSCE files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is

```
 The following packages are referenced using Rcpp::depends attributes \ 
 however are not listed in the Depends, Imports or LinkingTo fields of\ 
 the package DESCRIPTION file: RcppProgress
```

which seems plausible given what you now posted for DESCRIPTION and NAMESPACE.

So here is what I would do:

1. Create the package using the skeleton generator as you have. Extend as neeed as you have.  Then ...
2. Run `R CMD build mypackage` then
3. Run `R CME check mypackage_1.2.3.tar.gz`

This should give you a clear idea as to whether *your* sources are in good shape.  After that, you can create a binary or zip or ... which your colleague should be able to utilise.

*Edit:* And you should of course grep for RcppProgress upon which you may indeed have an undeclared dependency.

Comment: Thanks Dirk. I'll run these to ensure everything is as it should be.

Comment: The error points to not having dependency on the 'RcppProgress' package within the DESCRIPTION file. My code does have a progress meter, but it is generated via R::utils. Why would such an error be expressed when RcppProgress is not employed within my package?

Comment: You will have to debug the R packages `tools` and `utils` used for these checks then.  Usually they are right, and we are wrong.

Comment: Thanks again! When using build() from R::devtools (essentially a wrapper to R CMD BUILD), the 'binary' argument is set to FALSE by default, and a tar.gz file is generated. Setting binary = TRUE creates a .tgz file. My colleague is operating under a Linux system. Do you know this may be the source of issues around not being able to install on a different OS?

Comment: You are using functions I do not use, and you are having problems I do not have.  I usually recommend the _documented R commands_ so if I were you I'd re-read [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html).